# How to use filter in ng-if and variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-ng-if

In this example, I use filter in the [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), but how do I use it in a variable and `ng-if`, something like:

```
{{languages.length | filter: {available: true}}}
```

and

```
ng-if="languages.length == 0 | filter: {available: true}"
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/to7z06ma/).

---

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>There are {{languages.length}} languages in total.</div>
    <div>??? There are {{languages.length}} languages available.</div>
    <div ng-if="languages.length == 0">??? Sorry, there are no languages available.</div>

    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="language in languages | filter: {available: true}">{{language.name}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.languages = [
    {id:1, name:"German", available: false},    
    {id:2, name:"English", available: true},    
    {id:3, name:"French", available: false},  
    {id:4, name:"Italian", available: true},  
    {id:5, name:"Spanish", available: false}
];
```

Comment: i dont know why do you want to do this , simply you can do       
    <ol>
        <li ng-if="languages.length" ng-repeat="language in languages | filter: {available: true}">{{language.name}}</li>
    </ol>

Comment: I simply want to display how many languages are available, just as I display the number of total languages. I could make a function to do this and do the filtering in JavaScript but I would expect there to be a way to do this in Angular syntax in the HTML code.

Comment: Sometimes short function in $scope is more readable than spagetti code in html.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>There are {{languages.length}} languages in total.</div>
    <div>There are {{(languages|filter:{available:true}).length}} languages available.</div>
    <div ng-if="(languages|filter:{available:true}).length == 0">Sorry, there are no languages available.</div>

    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="language in languages | filter: {available: true}">{{language.name}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to update previous answer, no need to filter three times, create new variable 'filtered' on first filter:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>There are {{languages.length}} languages in total.</div>
    <div>There are {{(filtered = (languages|filter:{available:true})).length}} languages available.</div>
    <div ng-if="filtered.length == 0">Sorry, there are no languages available.</div>       
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="language in filtered">{{language.name}}</li>
    </ol>

    filtered=[{{filtered}}]
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/to7z06ma/18/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-if="(answerText|lowercase)=='true'">T</div>
```

`<div ng-if="(answerText|lowercase)=='false'">F</div>`

This works for me